# How do I get rid of the "opened application" indicator on Plank? (Ubuntu 18.04, Cinnamon)

Tags: 18.04, cinnamon, plank

There is a blue light icon below any open programs on Plank. I have disabled the function to have icons on plank that are not pinned to it, but the blue light persists on icons that are pinned. I haven't found any answers on how to get rid of it.

[image]

Comment: Those little blue lights below the icons are used to show that applications are running and / or open whether the application is pinned or not to the plank.

Comment: I know what they are for, Terrance, but I want to remove them.

Comment: So, in other words you just don't want to know if applications are running or not?

Comment: I suppose so. I just don't like how the blue light looks.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to my own question by looking into the source code of Plank. I'll post my answers here so if anyone else would like to get rid of the running app indicator, they'll be able to. First I gave myself root by entering:

```
sudo -i
```

and I entered in my password to gain root privileges. I then entered

```
gedit /usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme
```

You don't have to put "Transparent," that's just the theme I'm using. If you're not using transparent, then insert whatever theme you're using. From here, a text editor will pop up, and you will be allowed to edit it. If there is already a value for IndicatorSize, replace the value with 0. If there is not, then type in

```
IndicatorSize=0
```

on a new line. Now, all you will have to do is hit ctrl+s, and your running application indicators will be no more!